# Repeated conflicts on pull --rebase after got merge

Tags: git, github, merge, git-rebase

**Here is the scenario:**
I had created branch1 out of master some days back. Then, there were some pushes on branch1 and some pushes on master. I want to keep branch1 in daily sync with master so that when I merge branch1 into master finally, it already has those changes. So, I decide to merge master into branch1 everyday.

Now, **here is what I did**:

1. `git checkout master` > `git pull --rebase origin master`
2. `git checkout branch1` > `git pull --rebase origin branch1`
3. `git merge master`
4. I resolved the conflicts, staged the files and then did a local commit for the merge.
5. Now, I do a `git pull --rebase origin branch1`

Now, it shows me all the conflicts that I had just resolved as part of my merge. Why is this so?
I had to resolve all the conflicts again and then stage them. and then say `git rebase --continue`

> The question is why did it happen? Whats happening behind the scene?

Comment: Is someone else committing to branch1? Why the 5th step? Did you mean to push to origin?

Comment: Yes...while I was merging there were some pushes on branch1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't pushed the changes after the merge. So effectively the remote contains changes before the merge. The next pull would mark conflicts just like it did when the original merge occurred.

One way to avoid it would be to enable [rerere](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

Also IMHO, I thing rebasing master would be a better strategy than merging

Comment: So, when I have committed locally with all the conflicts resolved. It will simply pull the latest changes from the server and then will play the merge commits. Isn't it? The question is if I have resolved the conflicts already...y is it required again? Or should I be doing a normal git pull to avoid it? BTW, @TheGeorgeous thanks for the link.. its a useful one

Comment: A normal pull may or may not avoid it. Git simply compares the files you have and the ones you pulled. It does not remember your resolution(yet). As far as git is concerned the the two versions have conflicts.

Comment: If I do a `git pull origin branch1`, it will play the remote commits on top of the merge commit.. And when I do a `git pull --rebase origin branch1`, it will play the merge commits on top of the remote commits.. Is this right? So, the question is when I do a `git pull --rebase origin branch1`, when does git find a conflict? is it while playing the merge commit on top of remote commit? if thats the case, havent I already created a merge commit just for that?

Comment: Also @TheGeorgeous Can you help me understand the rebasing strategy a little? And how it may be a better strategy? I want to compare the two strategies

Comment: when you do `git pull --rebase origin branch1`, it will find the common diverging point and play the commits based on when it was committed. Can't explain more about it without seeing the working tree.

Comment: Rebasing master rather that merging master will let you keep master as a base for branch1 since you intend to merge branch1 back into master anyway. That will help only if the other person committing to branch1 also does the same. Or else you will end up with the same situation